# Game compatibility

Tags: games, compatibility

I was wondering if Ubuntu supports games like Battlefield, Minecraft, etc. Because the OS seems cool, but I want to still be able to play my games.

Thanks,
Ryan J

Answer (score 1):

Games on linux come in a few flavours.

- First, there are games designed for linux only. For example [TuxRacer](http://tuxracer.sourceforge.net/)
- Then games ported to linux. [Many steam games are now ported and more are planned](http://store.steampowered.com/browse/linux/).
- Finally,  [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) and [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) provide compatibility for many windows games

[Minecraft](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/minecraft-installer-for-ubuntu) can be installed on ubuntu. For other games it is worth googleing to see if people have got them running.